# Is there an expression for being the weakest student in a class?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

we say *she tops the class every year* meaning she has the greatest performance in her class per annum. Now how can we say someone has the weakest performance in a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways we can say someone was at the ***bottom*** of the class.

NOAD defines *bottom* as:

> the lowest position in a competition or ranking

so that word can be used. The word you've used – weakest – can also be used, especially in conjunction with *performer* or *performance*.

> Of all the students in my class last year, Bob was the *weakest performer*.

If you want a more humorous way to say it, you could say something like:

> Bob was *on the far left of my bell curve* last year.

but expressions like that might be considered insensitive or unprofessional, and therefore should be used with caution.

Comment: +1 How about "Bob achieved the class' largest negative deviation from the mean"?